# Hide Indicator in UIActivityIndicatorView in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

How can i disable or hide the Indicator in the UIActivityIndicatorView?

```
public class ActivityView : UIActivityIndicatorView {

    public ActivityView (CGRect frame) : base (frame){

    }
    public bool IsLoading {
        get {
            return !this.Hidden;
        }
        set {
            if (value) {
                this.Hidden = false;
                this.StartAnimating ();
            } else {
                this.StopAnimating ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this code not working?

Comment: this code works, but i don't want to see anymore the indicator gif

Comment: You mean from ac indicator you want to remove gif & only want circular process bar like android apps?

Comment: i just want a white screen without anything, and then put a gif or lottie into that view. But i have the loading gif and don't know how to hide.

Comment: Why not, create a custom view with animated image view, which you have total control

Comment: Because i need to re-edit all the methods from UIActivityIndicatorView and i just need hide the indicator. the solution was put TintColor and Color on Clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this:

```
    this.TintColor = UIColor.Clear;
    this.Color = UIColor.Clear;
```

in this part:

```
if (value) {
    ...
    this.TintColor = UIColor.Clear;
    this.Color = UIColor.Clear;
}
```